# Creating multiple server instances and accompanying Cloudflare tunnels using for_each

Tags: terraform, terraform-modules

I'm learning Terraform and trying to write my code as DRY as possible. I'm stuck on modules and enumeration. I want to achieve the following.

- For a list of named servers, create a server instance in Google Cloud, and for each server create a Cloudflare tunnel. The token of which is passed into the Google Cloud instance where the tunnel software will be run to connect back to Cloudflare.

I have two modules, Modules/Cloudflare and Modules/GCP. Both work fine if I just call them once. It will create a server, and a tunnel, and I can get the cloudflare_tunnel.tunnel_token back to a script that runs on the Google instance hosting the cloudflared tunnel software.

But I want to use a for_each so I can create multiple instances of both servers and tunnels.

Here is my main.tf from the root module. When I run the code below, it seems to try and create only one tunnel and assign it to both servers.

What am I missing? I've tried to find it in the documentation, but I can't piece it together.

```
variable "servers" {
  default = {
    "server1" = {
      name = "terraform1"
    },
    "server2" = {
      name = "terraform1"
    }
  }   
}

module "cloudflare_tunnel" {
  source = "./modules/cloudflare/tunnel"
  for_each = var.servers

  name = each.value.name
  cloudflare_account_id = var.cloudflare_account_id
  cloudflare_zone_id    = var.cloudflare_zone_id
  cloudflare_zone       = var.cloudflare_zone
}

module "gcp_server" {
  source = "./modules/gcp"
  for_each = var.servers

  name = each.value.name
  startup_script = "server-setup.sh"
  cloudflare_tunnel_token = module.cloudflare_tunnel[each.key].tunnel_token
  machine_type = var.gcp_machine_type
  image = var.gcp_instance_image
}
```

I tried moving the two module blocks from the root main.tf into another module, and then enumerating a single module in the root which then passes the each.value.name. But I couldn't make that work. I had problems with how to pass in the required variables from the root to each of the modules.

When I run the above code, I get the error. Why is it not creating two tunnels? I have a for_each in that module block.

> Error: failed to create Argo Tunnel: You already have a tunnel with this name. Delete the existing tunnel, or choose a different name for your new tunnel (1013)
> │
> │   with module.cloudflare_tunnel["server1"].cloudflare_tunnel.tunnel,
> │   on modules/cloudflare/tunnel/tunnel.tf line 7, in resource "cloudflare_tunnel" "tunnel":
> │    7: resource "cloudflare_tunnel" "tunnel" {
> │

This must be a common practice. What is the recommended way to structure my code?

Comment: "But I couldn't make that work." - what does it mean? What **exactly** is happening? Any errors?

Comment: I have edited my original post with more details.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear, you can't have two tunnels called `terraform1`. You need different name for each tunnel:

```
variable "servers" {
  default = {
    "server1" = {
      name = "terraform1"
    },
    "server2" = {
      name = "terraform2"
    }
  }   
}
```